# I want to use following window in my application , but I am not getting what to use for this?

Tags: javascript, html

[image: so Image is showing that different icons are there.]

What should i use if I want to add this kind of window in the website?

Comment: Now wait! You want to use something on your web page which you don't know what it is?

Comment: its kind of window but what kind of  component i should use for this ? that  is the question .

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery UI Draggable widget to create a DIV that can be dragged freely over your webpage. Then, you can customise that DIV with CSS according to your needs.

**JQuery UI#Draggable** : http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#entry-examples